# Ruby gem Factory Bot:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, factory-bot

My goal is to create a factory with a few fields with the same value,
for example I want that name and full_name be equal.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :brand do
    n = Faker::Company.name
    name      { n }
    full_name { n }
  end
end
```

The above approach doesn't work, because **n** get value only one time.

So, how to eval some block to share its data with a few dynamic fields?

---

Another case: I have YML file with brands, and method **get_random_brand** which returns hash with brands fields:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :brand do
    b = get_random_brand
    name      { b['name'] }
    full_name { b['full_nam'] }
  end
end
```

I understand that *factory do* when the factory definition is read.

How to evaluate **get_random_brand** only ones per each factory created?

Comment: Try creating and using a ruby variable outside the FactoryBot scope to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dependent attributes](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Dependent_Attributes) are actually really simple in FactoryBot as you just call the method for the other attribute in the block:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :brand do
    name      { Faker::Company.name }
    full_name { name }
  end
end
```

You can for example do:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    name  { Faker::Name.name }
    email { name.downcase.tr(' ', '.') + "@example.com" }
  end
end
```

> The above approach doesn't work, because n get value only one time.

Thats because the `factory ... do`  block is evaluated when the factory definition is read. Not every time the factory is used.

Comment: Ok, please look at second use case.

Comment: I would say the second use case is just a misuse of FactoryBot as a fixtures mechanism which it is not. If its even possible you´re just using a hammer on a screw.